# SQL Server 2012 : update a column based on min value from another table's column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, min

```
CREATE TABLE #TBLA (id int, numb int, value int)
INSERT INTO #TBLA 
VALUES (1,3,24),
       (1,4,14),
       (2,2,61),
       (2,1,12),       
       (2,3,54)



CREATE TABLE #TBLB (ID int, Value int)
INSERT INTO #TBLB (ID)
VALUES (1),(2)
```

I want to update #TBLB value column so that the value is eual to the min(numb) from table A.
Expected result :
TblB

```
id value 
1   24
2   12
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE #TBLB
SET Value = A.value 
FROM #TBLA A
JOIN 
(select B.ID, min(A.numb)  as mi
from #TBLA A 
join #TBLB B ON a.id = B.id 
GROUP BY B.ID) res 
ON A.id = res.ID and a.numb = res.mi
```

Comment: This works if we have different numbs per id. which is highly unlikely. need more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE 
AS (
    SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Numb ASC) rn 
    FROM #TBLA
   )
UPDATE B
 SET B.Value = C.value
FROM #TBLB B 
INNER JOIN CTE C ON B.ID = C.id AND C.rn = 1
```

Comment: @user3294322 try now I have fixed the issue.